# How to find the total number of marbles?

Tags: probability

A jar has only red green and blue marbles . If it is three times as likely that you randomly pick a red marble for a green one and five times as likely that you pick a green one for a blue marble. What could be the possible total number of marbles ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Denote balls by **R,G** and **B**.

**R** is $thrice$ likely as **G**, so, **R=3G**
**G** is $5$ times as likely as **B**, so, **G=5B**
$$R=3G=3(5B)=15B$$
Let there be **n B** balls, $$B=n$$
So, $$G=5B=5n$$ 
And, $$R=15B=15n$$

So, there are **n B**, **5n G** and **15n B** balls.

> Total balls are $$n+5n+15n=21n$$ where **n** is a natural number.

Answer (score 0):

It is a multiple of $21=1+5+15$, because if you have $n$ blue marbles, you should have $5n$ green and $15n$ red marbles.

Comment: Thanks I for some reason didn't think of it that way